# Is a subscribe in an error callback of a subscription an antipattern?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say you have below code. Would it be ok or is this not a good practice in reactive programming?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.beerService
      .getBeers()
      .subscribe({
        next: (beers) => {
          console.log(beers);
          this.beers = beers;
          this.title = beers[0].name;
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          errorHandler.subscribe();
        },
      });
  }
```

Comment: You can use https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError

Comment: The catchError catches an error in the stream but doesn't say anything about starting a different subscription in that case

Comment: catchError : Catches errors on the observable to be handled by returning a new observable or throwing an error.

Comment: It would be good if you could elaborate on what you are trying to achive with that 2nd subscribe. I would not necessarily say that it's an anitpatern, but you should be careful with it and there might be better options.

Comment: The errorhandler is an observable which returns an object whether the error was handled succesfully. So it's a different type of observable than the beers (array of objects containing a name property)

Answer (score 0):

Use `catchError`. In here u can do further manipulation. For details check this [url](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/).

Usage example:

```
http$
.pipe(
    catchError(err => {
        console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
        return throwError(err);
    })
)
.subscribe(
    res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
    err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
    () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
);
```